# check for characters and spaces using ASCII fails for other languages

Tags: javascript, ascii, multilingual

If we allow only chars and spaces we usually compare ASCII values in javascript. But what if we support multiple language, the check fails to work. Please advise me on this, any other way considering other languages too... 
The javascript we usually use is like that -->

```
function charAndSpacesOnly(objEvent) {
    if((objEvent.keyCode>=97 && objEvent.keyCode<=122) || (objEvent.keyCode>=65 && objEvent.keyCode<=90) || (objEvent.keyCode==32) || (objEvent.keyCode==45)) {      
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return false;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you very strictly allow only the 26 letters of the latin alphabet, without any diacritics, let alone eastern, cyrillic or chinese characters.

You *could* extend the if to support all those characters. Just grab a table from the internet that contains all these codes, and within a day or two you can implement every single sensible unicode character range.

But I think you should rather ask yourself if you need this limitation. People can always enter garbage if they want, and is `AaAaAaAaAa` (which is fine by your check) really more valid than `Golez Trol the 3rd`?

PS: Your `else {return false;}` is obsolete.

Comment: ASCII only contains English characters, How do i validate characters from other languages.

Comment: What makes you think your characters are in ASCII? You are bound to the keycodes, but they are not exactly ASCII as well. But I think you're right: you will probably not get a Chinese keycode, ever. I think, rather than validating keypresses, you'd better check the context of the input (or whatever) you are dealing with. That way you can also prevent people from pasting invalid characters. Capturing keypresses is just not safe. But still, I think you shouldn't need checks like this at all.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has anything to do with `objEvent.keyCode<=122`. So all character after 122 (other language) are excluded.

Comment: The condition says A to Z, a to z, space and - are accecpted. Anything else gets omitted.

Comment: That is the point. Characters of other languages are above ASCII 127 so omitting those make it not working.